# Render new element onClick in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and am trying to render a new element onClick:

```
      var LoginButton = React.createClass({
       ..............
       ..............
      clickHandle : function() {
        this.rememberMe = {
            active: localforage.getItem('rememberMe', function (err, key) {
                return key;
            })
        };
        if (this.rememberMe.active == true || this.rememberMe.active == 'checked')
        {
            document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
        }
        else {
            React.render(<wantToRemember />, document.getElementById('loginbuttonhere'));
        }
        return this.rememberMe.active;

    },
```

This is the element that should appear:

```
var wantToRemember = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function () {
            return {
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'block',
                top: '20px',
                width: '100px',
                height: '100px'
            }
        },

        render : function () {
            return (
                    <div className="rememberPopup" style={this.state}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="staylogin">
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <label for="checkbox">Angemeldet bleiben</label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="remember" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't appear, instead react renders this html:

```
<wanttoremember data-reactid=".1"></wanttoremember>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing some pretty basic stuff wrong, but can't figure out what. Isn't it possible to call different elements like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `react.js` component name begins with a lower-case letter, it should start with an upper-case leter: `var WantToRemember = React.createClass(...)` and `React.render(<WantToRemember />,...`.

The JSX compiler requires for component names to begin with an upper-case letter (see [jsx docs on this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)):

> To render a React Component, just create a local variable that starts with an upper-case letter:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({/*...*/});
var myElement = <MyComponent someProperty={true} />;
React.render(myElement, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a React element to React.render instead of the tag itself, something like this:

```
React.render(
  React.createElement(wantToRemember)
);
```

Comment: This answer is actually a more correct JSX behavior and pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29799455/95190